# Where to find proper documentation for `pywinauto`?

Tags: python, pywinauto

On the documentation page for `pywinauto.application.Application` [HERE](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=pywinauto.window#pywinauto.application.Application) you find some methods, but it seems not all are mentioned. I just ran the following code to open an existing application and to focus on its window/application(?; not sure what the difference is):

```
dialog = Desktop(backend="uia")["MyProgram"]
if not dialog.exists():
    dialog = Application(backend='uia').start(path, timeout=300)["MyProgram"]

dialog.set_focus()
dialog.ManageFirmware.click_input()
```

But the method `set_focus` does not seem to be explained in the documentation. Do I understand something wrong here?

And what is the difference between `Desktop`, `Application` and `Window`...?

Comment: I usually just use the `<searchterm> site:<document-website>` search on Google. For example, [set_focus site:https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io](https://www.google.com/search?q=set_focus+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fpywinauto.readthedocs.io&oq=set_focus+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fpywinauto.readthedocs.io) has [this](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper.set_focus) as top result. Would that help..?

Comment: If you KNOW you are looking for `set_focus` to set the focus, you don't need google or the documentation, because you know already! I do not know what other methods there are and what they are doing!

Comment: Oh, I understood your "But the method set_focus does not seem to be explained in the documentation. " so that you were looking for explanation what the `set_focus` does. What is your question?

Comment: No. I wanted to know if there does exist a more complete documentation somewhere. Or do I have to "guess" my way through `pywinauto`?

Comment: Are you looking for a general tutorial or "Getting Started" pages..?

Comment: That also would be nice. But please do not link to https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html as this "getting started" page is totally useless in my opinion. It does neither explain the differences between Desktop/Application/Window, nor some general features to find elements or even to click on elements with are totally essential for apps. There is ZERO reference to the word "click"...

Comment: As you've seen, `set_focus` *is* documented, it's just not a method of the `Application` class. Do you have evidence that there are undocumented methods on the `Application` class that you're missing…?

Comment: @deceze  Where is it documented?

Comment: [`set_focus`](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.base_wrapper.html#pywinauto.base_wrapper.BaseWrapper.set_focus)

Answer (score 3):

You will first need to understand the basic definitions the documentation uses, which are laid out here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html. It tells you about "controls" and "dialogs" and so on, and also describes how you get from an `Application` to a window/dialog etc. through attribute access.

Then there's an entire section dedicated to [Methods available to each different control type](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls_overview.html). It lists all those different methods, including `set_focus`.

Under the hood there are a ton of different classes implementing all this functionality through inheritance, and since the high level interface to them is fairly dynamic and any one attribute access may return different objects depending on what you're dealing with, it's harder to read the documentation "bottom up". Which is why the "top down" documentation mentioned above exists.

If you want to go there, you'll see that [`Application.__getattribute__`/`__getitem__`](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=pywinauto.window#pywinauto.application.Application) return "the specified dialog". What exactly that is will probably depend on the situation, so there's no link from there to any specific other class. The `set_focus` method in particular is implemented in [`HwndWrapper`](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper), which yeah, you probably wouldn't have guessed.

Thus it's easier to stick to the [high level "top down" documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls_overview.html) which tells you that `set_focus` is available on *all controls* and a [dialog](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls_overview.html#dialog) in particular will have other things you can look up from there.

Comment: Yes, it tells you how to specify a control, but does not explain what a control is...

Comment: [*"A control is GUI element at any level of a hierarchy. This definition includes window, button, edit box, grid, grid cell, bar etc."*](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html)

Comment: Can you provide a HowTo which describes really to USE pywinauto? To get texts from window/dialogsa/controls, CLICK on controls etc, find elements, handle lists etc?

Comment: I'm sorry? There's a gentle documentation to ease you into it with loads of examples and linking to more example code. Understand that it's a fairly complex project, because it's trying to contain the entire UI paradigm with tons of details. The right way to go about it is to get into the right mindset by following the introduction carefully, and once you have the basic understanding in place you can look at the list of methods available for controls and go from one attribute to the next from there.

Comment: It is extremly complicated. I am sorry for my questions

Comment: Even though this may not be the answer you hope for, "getting a feeling for it" is important for most projects, and apparently specifically with this one. You need to dick around with the basic how-tos until you get a more or less intuitive feeling for how to access what items through attributes, and then the list of methods will explain the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253424/discussion-between-alex-and-deceze).

Comment: Ok, then next up: examples! Let me try to run and understand the examples. I am pretty sure I have a ton of questions ...